# Implementing Pandora FMS for monitoring

Tags: server, monitoring, flash-media-server, zone, pandora

So, I'm implementing a monitoring solution in site 6 which will be used to monitor all activity in all sites (from 1 to 6 positioned in two different zones and connected with a switch) and please note that basically all servers use CentOS as an OS.

What is the best practice to implement Pandora FMS positioning it in the DMZ or the LAN part or a Lan to its own ? Should I use remote monitoring or local monitoring ?

[Site 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TMQr.png)

Comment: Please feel free to point out any architectural errors

Answer (score 0):

Inside your PandoraFMS configurarion you could have details about your servers or network arquitecture (ips, os, services runnings, etc) because you need it to monitor your servers...

The best option for me is to place PandoraFMS server in a secure network behind a firewall and use remote monitoring so you can access de DMZ safelly.

Hope it helps!